# "Contract value not updated in Ganache after calling a custom method using Web3 and Solidity"

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, nft, ganache

I wanted to play a little with blockchain technology so I wanted to create a basic NFT market place.

Im using Solidity and Ganache.

This is the contract that I made:

```
contract PixelPurseMarketPlace is ERC721, Ownable {
using SafeMath for uint256;

uint256 private _totalSupply;
uint256 private _nextTokenId;
address payable private _pixelPurseCharityAddress;
uint256 private _pixelPurseCharityPercentage;
address payable private _pixelPurseAddress;
uint256 private _pixelPursePercentage;

constructor() ERC721("PixelPurse", "PPTM"){
    _totalSupply = 0;
    _nextTokenId = 1;
}

function setCharityAddress(address payable pixelPurseCharityAddress) external onlyOwner 
{
    _pixelPurseCharityAddress = pixelPurseCharityAddress;
}

function viewCharityAddress() external view onlyOwner returns (address) {
    return _pixelPurseCharityAddress;
}

function setCharityPercentage(uint256 pixelPurseCharityPercentage) external onlyOwner {
    require(pixelPurseCharityPercentage >= 0, "Charity percantage must be >= 0");
    require(pixelPurseCharityPercentage <= 100, "Charity percantage must be <= 0");
    _pixelPurseCharityPercentage = pixelPurseCharityPercentage;
}

function viewCharityPercentage() external view onlyOwner returns (uint256){
    return _pixelPurseCharityPercentage;
}

function viewCharityRaisedFunds() external view onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
    return _pixelPurseCharityAddress.balance;
}

function setApplicationAddress(address payable pixelPurseAddress) external onlyOwner {
    _pixelPurseAddress = pixelPurseAddress;
}

function viewApplicationAddress() external view onlyOwner returns (address) {
    return _pixelPurseAddress;
}

function setApplicationFee(uint256 pixelPursePercentage) external onlyOwner {
    require(pixelPursePercentage >= 0, "Charity percantage must be >= 0");
    require(pixelPursePercentage <= 100, "Charity percantage must be <= 0");
    _pixelPursePercentage = pixelPursePercentage;
}

function viewApplicationFee() external view onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
    return _pixelPursePercentage;
}

function viewApplicationBalance() external view onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
    return _pixelPurseAddress.balance;
}
}
```

Then, using Truffle I created a new migration, added the PixelPurse contract and deployed it to Ganache into first account.
Now when im going to **CONTRACTS** tab it appears there with the storage

```
{ 15 items
_owner:address"0xb79A9154E9E4D4f86F..."
_name:string"PixelPurse"
_symbol:string"PPTM"
_owners:{}mapping0 items
_balances:{}mapping0 items
_tokenApprovals:{}mapping0 items
_operatorApprovals:{}mapping0 items
_totalSupply:uint0
_nextTokenId:uint1
_pixelPurseCharityAddress:address"0x000000000000000000..."
_pixelPurseCharityPercentage:uint0
_pixelPurseAddress:address"0x000000000000000000..."
_pixelPursePercentage:uint0
}
```

Now when I want to set let's say the pixelPursePercentage I created this js script

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const PixelPurse = require("../build/contracts/PixelPurseMarketPlace.json");

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

async function test() {
  const account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const contractABI = PixelPurse.abi;
  const contractAddress = account[0];
  contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

  const newFeePercentage = 10; // set the new fee percentage here
  const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
  const gasFee = await contract.methods
    .setApplicationFee(newFeePercentage)
    .estimateGas({ from: contractAddress });

  await contract.methods
    .setApplicationFee(newFeePercentage)
    .send({ from: contractAddress, gasPrice: gasPrice, gas: gasFee });
}
test();
```

The transcation appears in the account transaction history, but it does not change the value in the storage.

What I want to do is to create a web page and to be able to edit the address I'm sending funds to, edit the percentage of a transaction that is being made.